# Swift: Updating struct variables?

Tags: swift, struct

I’m fairly new to Swift, and I’ve stumbled across this problem today which will help me a lot if answered. The code below explains my issue:

```
struct Foo {
  var x: Float
  mutating func change() {
    x += 1
  }
}

struct Bar {
  var y: Float
}

var foo = Foo(x: 1)
let bar = Bar(y: foo.x)

foo.change()

print(foo.x) // 2.0
print(bar.y) // 1.0 (how can I make this 2.0 as well?)
```

I thought I might have to use pointers but I have no idea how to, and I have no clue if that’d even work.
Any ideas will help!

Comment: Unclear what the question is. You cannot change anything about `bar` because you declared it with `let`. And you are not doing anything that would change `bar` in any case, so what would change it?

Comment: Pretend it was var. Bad example

Comment: Programming is not about pretending. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get what you want here is to define `Bar` to keep a reference to `Foo`. And since you want a change to an instance of `Foo` to carry over to the reference held by a `Bar`, you would need to make `Foo` a class instead of a struct.

Here's one possible solution:

```
class Foo {
    var x: Float

    init(x: Float) {
        self.x = x
    }

    func change() {
        x += 1
    }
}

struct Bar {
    var foo : Foo
    var y : Float { return foo.x }

    init(foo: Foo) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}

var foo = Foo(x: 1)
let bar = Bar(foo: foo)

foo.change()

print(foo.x) // 2.0
print(bar.y) // 2.0 as asked
```

Comment: So there's no way to do it without a class?

Comment: If `Foo` is a struct, then each assignment gives you a new copy.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
let bar = Bar(y: foo.x)
```

the value `foo.x` (`1`) is **copied** inside `Bar`.

So doesn't exist no further connection between `foo.x` and `bar.x`.

This happens because in Swift params are passed by value.

### Solution

First of all we need a generic wrapper

```
class Wrapper<Element> {
    var element: Element
    init(element: Element) {
        self.element = element
    }
}
```

now we can redefine `Foo` and `Bar`

```
struct Foo {
    var x: Wrapper<Float>
    mutating func change() {
        x.element += 1
    }
}

struct Bar {
    var y: Wrapper<Float>
}
```

> As you can see now `Foo` and `Bar` doesn't hold the `Float` value but a reference to a `Float` value. We will use this to make the foo and bar value to reference the same `Float` value.

Finally we can test that the value is changed across both structures

```
var foo = Foo(x: Wrapper<Float>(element: 1))
let bar = Bar(y: foo.x)
foo.change()

print(foo.x.element) // prints 2.0
print(bar.y.element) // prints 2.0
```

Comment: The OP seems to understand this. The question is asking how to get around this.

Comment: @rmaddy: Ok I added a possible solution.